# What is the correct terminology for this type of HTML vertical tag-pairing?

Tags: tags, ide, terminology, aptana

What is the correct terminology for this type of HTML vertical tag-pairing?

[image: Example of the vertical tag-pairing I'm referring to.]

Also wondering whether it can be enabled in Aptana Studio 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually figured this one out myself, by accident - was researching another code editor called "Sublime Text" and read [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/), which if you scroll down to the 6th section explains that the terminology for these vertical linkages is "Indent Guides."  And also, it appears that this feature is not available for Aptana - too bad.